# Monitor folder for new file and copy file to clipboard

Tags: macos, automation

I need to optimise a repetitive task. The task is as follows:

1.) User saves file using third party program to a specific folder.

2.) Folder is monitored for changes, change is determined. < - assistance needed.

3.) Latest file is copied to user's clipboard. < - assistance needed.

The process needs to take less than 3 seconds from the time step 1 finishes.

Can the above be accomplished through built in functions of OSX, if so can you point me in the right direction? If not, do you have suggestions for third party programs to accomplish this (preferably free).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the task that's being repeated as is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - it doesn't make sense to move a file to a folder only to then copy said file to the clipboard.  Also, you didn't clarify if you want the file itself in the clipboard (as if you were going to copy it to another location) or the contents of the file. All of this can be done in Applescript, but if you tell us the exact workflow you're trying to automate, you might get better results.

Comment: @Allan apologies, the final step is pasting the file into a third party application (Anki). It's not enough to simply move the file to the location Anki stores files, as it needs to be pasted into a specific field so a database can be updated. This part doesn't need to be automated. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I’m familiar with Anki and it doesn’t support Applescript so you’ll hit a major speedbump, if not a roadblock trying to automate that part of the process.  However, Anki does support bulk importing.  It might be a better idea to find out what the structure of the data is that you’re attempting to import and we get it into that file (like a CSV) via automation.  But, it’s still not clear if you’re trying to paste the entire file or the contents of the file into the field in Anki

Comment: @Allan bulk importing isn't really what I'm looking for a number of reasons.

I'll look into running running a script to monitor a folder, copy the latest file itself to the clipboard (all done outside of Anki) and then the user just pastes it themselves into Anki.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'll try make a hot key to copy the latest file from a specific folder.